# ¿Sufijo que signifique "planeta de"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sufijos, neologismos, prefijos

Si yo quisiera inventarme un nombre de país que haga referencia a algo, lo tengo fácil gracias a la partícula ***-landia***:

> [**-landia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MskXvbY)
>   De la t. de *Finlandia, Islandia, Jutlandia*, etc., y esta del germ. *-land* 'país', 'tierra'.
>
> 1. elem. compos. Significa 'sitio de', 'lugar de', generalmente en nombres propios. *Zumolandia, Fotolandia*.

¿El país de los tomates? *Tomatelandia*. ¿De los Ferrari? *Ferrarilandia*, etc.

Podría incluso utilizar otro afijo, ***-terra***, que no viene en el diccionario pero que significa "tierra" (del latín *terrae*) y que podemos encontrar en el nombre de Inglaterra ("tierra de los ingleses"), así como en algunos topónimos gallegos como Fisterra ("fin de la tierra" o "tierra del fin") o Ferrolterra ("tierra de Ferrol").

Pero ¿y si quisiera inventarme un nombre de planeta?
Por ejemplo: el planeta de los monos (que no simios). ¿*Monolandia*? ¿*Micoterra*? Será subjetivo, pero me parecen nombres de país (o de parque temático...), más que de un planeta entero.

**¿Existe algún elemento o afijo que signifique específicamente "*planeta de*"?** Y en caso de que no lo haya, ¿qué elementos del español podrían usarse para formar un nombre que deje claro que estamos hablando de un planeta?

Comment: Hay muchos más países terminados en [-ia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KrTqAy7) que en -landia, porque -ia es latino. Igual es más bonito tu "Tomatilandia" que "Tomatia".

Comment: Los que viven en Tomatilandia creen que hay un único Tomativerso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debemos recordar que **land** viene del germánico" **tierra/lugar**", sin embargo no de "tierra" de nombre del planeta, sino de "terreno" y planeta del griego **Errante**, pues era el nombre que se les daba a los astros que se movían en el cielo...

Otros términos para planeta son **astro** o **mundo**.

Ahora, el planeta de la leche... ¿el "lactoneta", el "lactoastro", "lactomundo"?

Comment: El país _lactoneta_ debe ser la leche :P

Comment: En realidad *planeta* no viene de plano, era *planeta* ya en latín y viene del griego *planete* que significa *errante* porque los planetas se veían como estrellas que se movían en el cielo

Answer (score 3):

Yo no descartaría muy rápidamente *terra* como elemento compositivo, ya que no solamente hace referencia a la tierra como "suelo" sino a la Tierra como planeta. Véanse palabras como *[terráqueo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZbVJnaX)*, "que representa el planeta", o *terraformación*, que no está en el DLE pero se usa con el sentido de "acondicionar un planeta para que sea habitable por el ser humano". A fin de cuentas, *tierra* también se usa, aunque tampoco lo recoge el DLE, para hablar de planetas potencialmente habitables por el hombre:

> La NASA descubre tres nuevas súper Tierras en un sistema a 100 años luz de distancia.

A lo mejor este elemento compositivo podría dar la sensación de que el planeta es habitable, y tú no quieres incluir esa parte. Pero vamos, no es descabellado nombrar a un planeta como *Novoterra*, por ejemplo. Así, el ejemplo *Micoterra* para "El planeta de los simios" tampoco lo veo mal.

Si queremos buscar algo un poco más genérico, podría ayudar esta lista de [nombres de planetas inventados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_planets_by_medium). De ahí veo que se podría usar un elemento compositivo muy básico:

> **[-ario, ria](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3YvWLaw)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. -arius.
> ```
>
> 1. suf. Forma adjetivos que indican relación con la base derivativa.

Hay más acepciones, pero esa es la que nos interesa. En la lista se citan los siguientes ejemplos que siguen esta pauta (nótese que en inglés el sufijo sería *[-arium, -aria](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-arium)*, este último para el plural):

- Solaria (aparece en novelas de Isaac Asimov).
- Omnivarium (aparece en novelas de David Brin).
- Aquarius (usando el sufijo latino, aparece en el anime Space Battleship Yamato).

Añado otro más que no está en la lista:

- Dozaria (aparece en Star Trek: Deep Space Nine).

También he visto un par de casos de nombres que acaban en *-world*, caso ya cubierto por Mike. Por lo demás, no hay ningún otro patrón visible. Así, tus ejemplos podrían quedar, con más o menos estilo, así:

- Platanaria (planeta de los plátanos).
- Monorium (planeta de los monos, por aquello de usar la versión inglesa).
- Lactorius (planeta de la leche, usando el sufijo latino).

Comment: @walen respuesta ampliada con más opciones, a ver si estas te gustan más. :-)

Comment: me recuerda a "terraria" el mundo de los terrarios

Comment: como nombrariamos a la tierra:
terricolandia el mundo de los terricolas? 
Terriconeta el planeta de los terricolas? 
terricoria ? 
terricorium? 
terrastro?
terricomundo?