# ¿Existe un proceso para inventar palabras?

Tags: lingüística, neologismos, diccionarios

Creo que esto es un tema que se ha tocado muchas veces en el S.SE, pero no he encontrado la pregunta como tal.

Naturalmente la sociedad va evolucionando poco a poco, y con ello las maneras de expresarnos y comunicarnos, así que muchas veces faltan las palabras, a veces la palabra no solo es lo que falta, sino un sufijo en específico como en el caso de la pregunta [¿Sufijo que signifique "planeta de"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26174/sufijo-que-signifique-planeta-de).

Tal vez son los literatos y escritores los que tienen el trabajo de traernos nuevas palabras, y nuestro trabajo el adoptarlas y adaptarlas.

¿Pero existe algun proceso, reglas o método para crear palabras nuevas?

Comment: La gente inventa palabras todo el tiempo. Son como... las mutaciones: las hay de buenas, las hay de malas, pero las que se hacen su hueco son las que persisten y acaban siendo "válidas" porque las autoridades lingüísticas las recogen. Recuperando lo que se dice siempre: si no inventáramos palabras, aún estaríamos hablando en latín.

Comment: Hay una discepancia entre el título de la pregunta (¿Se puede inventar palabras?) y lo que realmente se pregunta (¿Existe algún proceso, reglas o método para crear palabras nuevas?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estamos hablando, si entiendo bien, de la invención deliberada de palabras (o más bien de [morfemas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morfema), es decir, de palabras completas y también de prefijos, sufijos y otras formas de [derivación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivaci%C3%B3n_(ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica))).

No son muy frecuentes las palabras nuevas inventadas deliberadamente que logran "prender" en el idioma (es decir, que sean adoptadas por los hablantes). En general se inventan palabras nuevas en las ciencias, pero aun cuando tengan éxito, muchas veces no salen del léxico de los especialistas o de un pequeño grupo de interesados. Los movimientos político-ideológicos, las religiones organizadas y otros grupos similares también pueden inventar palabras propias que no salen de su pequeño círculo.

¿Cómo se crean palabras nuevas en castellano? Hay que considerar dos aspectos: los materiales y la forma de combinarlos.

Los materiales de que disponemos para formar nuevas palabras son:

- palabras que ya existen, o partes reconocibles de palabras;
- prefijos y sufijos de derivación propios del castellano;
- palabras de otros idiomas modernos, como el inglés;
- palabras o partes de palabras de los idiomas clásicos (latín y griego).

Lo que podemos hacer con esos materiales es:

- poner uno junto a otro ([composición](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composici%C3%B3n_(ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica)) si son palabras completas, o [afijación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afijo) si son una palabra y un prefijo o sufijo);
- repetirlos total o parcialmente ([reduplicación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplicaci%C3%B3n_(ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica)));
- una combinación de estos dos anteriores y algún otro recurso (por ejemplo el [vesre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesre)).

En castellano tendemos a inventar palabras recurriendo al latín y al griego. Como dije al principio, me refiero a palabras creadas deliberadamente. Muchas palabras nuevas tienen un origen distinto pero ésas son las que la gente crea y adopta espontáneamente, no las "inventadas". Los escritores y poetas están en un punto intermedio, ya que pueden inventar a su gusto y lo hacen usando todos los recursos que mencioné arriba, pero rara vez logran que esas palabras inventadas lleguen realmente al idioma. No conozco ningún ejemplo en castellano. En otras lenguas se me ocurre como ejemplo la palabra «robot», que proviene de una obra de teatro del dramaturgo checo Karel Čapek. Es el único caso que recuerdo de una palabra inventada con un propósito literario que se haya convertido en un concepto común en decenas de lenguas.

Usar el latín y el griego como fuente es muy común entre nosotros y en otras lenguas de origen europeo, pero no en todas. En alemán, por ejemplo, se tienden a usar raíces germánicas, y por eso por ejemplo el hidrógeno es *Wasserstoff* (de *Wasser* "agua", paralelo al griego *hydro-*) y la palabra "expresión" se traduce como *Ausdruck* (de *aus-* "hacia afuera", paralela al latín *ex-*, y *druck-* "presionar, apretar"). En japonés la lengua de la cultura fue durante siglos el chino, por lo cual la mayoría de las palabras compuestas son de origen chino.

Podemos también crear palabras juntando palabras castellanas que ya tenemos. Una forma es unir sustantivos. En Argentina se dice ya como una única palabra *patamuslo* para referirse a la pata y el muslo de un pollo cocinados y servidos juntos. No sé quién inventó la palabra pero algún anónimo vendedor de comida para llevar debe haberlo hecho, y prendió.

Otra forma es unir verbo + sustantivo en una forma estándar, por ejemplo: *sacacorchos*, *cortaplumas*, *alcanzapelotas*. Quien inventó el lavavajillas debe haber también inventado la palabra.

Comment: "*Podemos también crear palabras juntando palabras castellanas que ya tenemos. Una forma es unir sustantivos.*"  Otro ejemplo podría ser el **baciyelmo** cervantino  (http://dle.rae.es/?id=4kkSDv6) o el más reciente **choripán** (http://dle.rae.es/?id=8zPf75i)